# What ServerName is given for AWS while creating vitual host?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

What `ServerName` is to be declared in `VirtualHost` in Amazon Web Service. I am defining

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/fortis_django"
ServerName ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/fortis
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/myfood"
ServerName ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/myfood
</VirtualHost>
```

also tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/fortis_django"
ServerName localhost/fortis
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/myfood"
ServerName localhost/fortis
</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting Apache gives error

> httpd: Couldn't determine server's fully qualified domain using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

name `ServerName` by default it is given `ServerName localhost:80` i made it comment.

Answer (score 1):

`ServerName` takes a fully qualified domain name, and optionally a port, but not a path like you're doing. A correct value could be for example:

> ServerName ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:80

or

> ServerName localhost:80

Comment: Did same but got same error ....

httpd: Couldn't determine server's fully qualified domain using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/fortis_django"
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ServerName localhost:80
</VirtualHost>

Comment: do you get the same if you define the `ServerName` in the main Apache configuration? (not within a `VirtualHost` config)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName fortis.com
   DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/fortis_django"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myfood.com
   DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/myfood"
</VirtualHost>
```

Where 'fortis.com' and 'myfood.com' your real domain names.
Based on this name apache will choose document root

Good luck!